# Query to BigQuery in Cloud Function running into error: invalid value at 'job.configuration.query'

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a query I'm trying to run a Google Cloud function that is running a query against a BigQuery database that I have on the same Google Cloud project. I have verified that the query is valid and can make the query manually. When I try running this code, I get the same error back after it calls the query:
"Exception from a finished function: Error: Invalid value at `job.configuration.query` (query), Starting an object on a scalar field".

Code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
const locationValue = 'us-east1';

...
...

const options = {
    query: sqlQuery,
    location: locationValue,
};

const [rows] = await bigqueryClient.query(options);
```

I have tried changing the location in the options value, tried making sure I have the BigQuery API info installed, tried other functions like `createQueryJob` and `getQueryResults` (which return the same error), and verified the service account has BigQuery permissions. I'm at a loss for what to try next to resolve this, as I can't find any documentation on this issue anywhere.

Comment: Have a look at the following sample ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query?hl=en#bigquery_query-nodejs

See if this runs.